How to get manual fsck log
I just had some issue with my filesystem and had to run fsck in manual mode while in initramfs.
I followed this advice and got the Ubuntu login screen eventually.
How can I get the fsck output now that I'm the graphical interface? I'd like to send it to support for further investigation.
I can see this, but not the log of actions I acutally did in manual mode:
$ sudo cat /run/initramfs/fsck.log
Log of fsck -C -a -T -t ext4 /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root 
Fri Sep 13 15:19:11 2024

/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root: recovering journal
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root contains a file system with errors, check forced.
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root: Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  

/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4

Fri Sep 13 15:19:11 2024
----------------
Log of fsck -C -a -T -t ext4 /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root 
Fri Sep 13 15:29:31 2024

/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root contains a file system with errors, check forced.
/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root: Inodes that were part of a corrupted orphan linked list found.  

/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY.
        (i.e., without -a or -p options)
fsck exited with status code 4

Fri Sep 13 15:29:32 2024
----------------
Log of fsck -C -a -T -t ext4 /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root 
Fri Sep 13 15:31:39 2024

/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root: clean, 1603836/30990336 files, 38822767/123952128 blocks

Fri Sep 13 15:31:39 2024
----------------

